# Calling an API from BroadcastReceiver android fails

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-volley, intentfilter

I have written a WifiBroadcastReceiver that is triggered when there is a change in Wifi state. I have used the below intent filter for the same.

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Whenever there is a change in wifi state, onReceive from WifiBroadcastReceiver is being called as expected. However, I am trying to make a API request in onReceive() method using volley library. This API request never completes for some reason. i.e. The callback onResponse() is never called.

I read about the problem with BroadcastReceiver and the usage of goAsync(). However, I was not able to implement it properly. Can anyone please help with a better way to call API from onReceive() method.

Below is the code that i have written in onReceive()

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
        NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if(info != null && info.isConnected()) {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            int networkId = wifiInfo.getNetworkId();
            notificationHelper.sendHighPriorityNotification("Hello "+user, "Connected to Wifi " + networkId, MapsActivity.class);
            
            // Making a POST API request
            callPostApi(context);

        }
    }

    private void callPostApi(final Context context) throws JSONException {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        String url = "https://xxxx:8080/endpoint";

        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        params.put("to", "+917989872829");
        params.put("content", "Success!");

        final String requestBody = params.toString();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
                        notificationHelper.sendHighPriorityNotification("Message", response.substring(0, 50), MapsActivity.class);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                params.put("Accept", "application/json");
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: @pareshgoel Can you please help me on this. I saw that you have answered a similar question few years back.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from a `BroadcastReceiver`. A `BroadcastReceiver` has a very short lifetime, it basically lives only until the call to `onReceive()` completes. You cannot perform network I/O or anything that takes significant amount of time in a `BroadcastReceiver`. You also cannot make the `BroadcastReceiver` wait until the network I/O finishes because that will block the broadcast dispatcher which is also not allowed.

What you should do is have your `BroadcastReceiver` start a `Service`, and perform your network I/O from the `Service`. There are tons of examples of this oj Stackoverflow and other websites.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @David. In that case, can i execute an AsyncTask to make API call ?

Comment: Not directly from a `BroadcastReceiver`, that's why you need to start a `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

I used Livedata instead of Service to invoke the API call from BroadcastReceiver and it's working fine for me.

Hope it will help someone.

Example:

```
private val broadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        when (intent?.action) {
            BROADCAST_UNAUTHORIZED_TOKEN -> {
                onLogoutRider()
            }

            BROADCAST_REFRESH_HOME -> {
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                        viewModel.updateRefreshHomeStatus(true)
                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//in your ViewModel class

```
private val _refreshHome = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
var refreshHome: LiveData<Boolean> = _refreshHome
 
 internal fun updateRefreshHomeStatus(state: Boolean) {
    _refreshHome.value = state
}
```

// in your fragment class

```
/**
 *  Refresh Home
 */
private fun subscribeRefreshHomeState() {
    viewModel.refreshHome.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        if (it) {
            viewModel.getAPICall()
        }
    }
}
```